# Call postgresql function with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem with writing a PHP code line with Laravel 8.
The following SQL line works in console:

```
SELECT archive.license('{"CC-BY-NC-ND-4.0"}');
```

The next line with Laravel does not work:

```
DB::select('SELECT archive.license(\'{"' . $code . '"}\')')
```

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERREUR:  la fonction archive.license(unknown) n'existe pas
> LINE 1: SELECT archive.license('{"CC-BY-NC-ND-4.0"}')

An idea of the way of writing this?
Thanks

Comment: It's saying the function doesn't exist. It could be a permissions issue, where the db user that Laravel is using doesn't have access to that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a raw select query using the DB facade. But remember to bind your parameters.

Try the following:

```
$params = [
    '{"' . $code . '"}'
];
DB::select('SELECT archive.license(?)', $params);
```